# Mysql cell contains contains list that needs to be formatted to be used for IN statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have these two tables:

training_course (Notice the column "deptId"...)
[image]

id_dept

[image]

The query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT dept FROM id_dept WHERE id IN (SELECT deptId FROM training_course WHERE id = '8')
```

But it won't give me the results I need. I could make a cross-reference table for ever courseName,but I was wondering if there was some trick in situations like this?

Comment: Which data type is "deptId"? Looks strange to me that you can have 2 values stored inside only one column.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_in_set()` to satisfy your query.  Then do research on junction tables and learn why storing integer ids in a string is a bad, bad, bad idea.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists of things.  It is called a table, not a string.

You can do what you want as:

```
SELECT dept
FROM id_dept
WHERE find_in_set(id, (SELECT deptId FROM training_course WHERE id = '8')) > 0;
```

or:

```
SELECT dept
FROM id_dept d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM training_course tc
              WHERE tc.id = '8' and
                    find_in_set(d.id, tc.deptId) > 0
             );
```

Comment: Lol. Yea I am learning, I am glad there are people out there like you that help us... I was totally thinking to myself that this defeats the idea of what tables are for, but I was not sure. Thanks!